# Angular-material md-tabs bar fixed and scrolling content

Tags: angular-material

As described in title I'm looking for a way to keep the md-tabs bar fixed at a certain position and having only the single  contents available for scrolling. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: I mean the single md-tab contents

Comment: what have you tried so far?  We want to help you but post your code so we can better see what will resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried following this post: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4408 but it doesn't work properly: http://pastebin.com/WrU1AHRf I set md-toolbar and md-tabs positions to be fixed and height: 100% as described in the post. I succeeded into making header and tags fixed but single md-tab scroll to just 100% height of the page and the remaining content is "hidden"

Comment: If it is not already solved, maybe [this can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35559283/3081756).

Comment: @skjorrface , If you have any solution?